# Share User Table between different websites for authorisation

Tags: backendless

New to Backendless but have done a considerable amount of their lessons to get a good understanding. Having searched the forums I haven't quite got the info I need.

1. If I have one App/account in Backendless, does this mean I only ever have one 'Users' Table?
2. For the sake of economy and thus not having to buy multiple Apps/Accounts on Backendless is there anyway to create additional 'User' tables for other websites I would like to connect to for user authorisation?
3. If, no, is there a way to do this? For example is there a way to add a new Column to Backendless 'Users' to somehow categorise the 'Users' by website/app? So I could user the User Authorisation from both Site A and Site B?

Thanks in advance for any advice in relation to this.

Stephen

PS I only use Backendless for the Backend and hope to connect in from both Bubble and Webflow (depending on the project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can have only one Users table in the application
2. You can create other tables, but you will not be able to use Backendless User API with the other tables
3. Sure, you can add a column like `project` and it can be a relation to the  Project table or something like that.

I do not recommend doing this, because such an economy may cause to the issues in the future.

Looks like you are trying to do a backendless inside the backendless.